# React Native Components Do Not Recognize Taps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have just recently switched to React navigation v6 in my RN app and I can't seem to understand why my `Button`(s) and `Touchable`(s) do not recognize `onPress` function the second time they are being pushed.

The scenario:

1. I launch Home Screen.
2. Press `go to test screen` button. The console prints the message.
3. On Test Screen press `go back`. The console prints the message. I go back.
4. Back on the Home Screen the button doesn't work anymore. Console does not print the message

Home.tsx

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 30 }}>
      <Button
        title='go to test screen'
        onPress={() => {
          console.log('pressed to test');
          navigate(TEST_SCREEN);
        }}
      />
</View>
```

TestScreen.tsx

```
<View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 30}}>
   <Button
     title='go back'
     onPress={() => {
       console.log('pressed go back');
       goBack();
     }}
   />
</View>
```

navigate func:

```
export function navigate(name: string, params?: any | undefined) {
  if (navigationRef.isReady()) {
    navigationRef.navigate(name, params);
  }
}
```

navigator:

```
const Home = createStackNavigator();

export default function HomeNavigator(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <Home.Navigator
      initialRouteName={HOME_SCREEN}
      screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
    >
      <Home.Screen name={HOME_SCREEN} component={HomeScreen} />
      <Home.Screen name={TEST_SCREEN} component={TestScreen} />
    </Home.Navigator>
  );
}
```

routes:

```
export const HOME_SCREEN = 'Home';
export const TEST_SCREEN = 'Test';
```

Comment: Could you recreate this issue with an expo snack?

Comment: why? this is not expo, it might work different on RN Cli

Comment: This is not using any expo-specific library. It helps to determine the problem.